# How to add a route to the volume controls

Tags: android, chromecast

I am updating our app to meet the new Google chromecast guidlines. One of the specifications states (Use the hardware buttons to change the volume level on the receiver. A visual volume slider (with a cast icon to the left of it) should only show when the hardware volume buttons are pressed). I'm assuming they mean something like this.

[image: Volume Example]

I can't seem to find anywhere were I can add set a flag to show this route or a place to add a custom route. I have looked all through the Companion app and have not found any place where this is done. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is a snippet of my code that sets up lock screen controls

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName());
    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiver);

    Intent remoteControlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    remoteControlIntent.setComponent(receiver);
    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, remoteControlIntent, 0);
    RemoteControlClient ctrlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
    ctrlClient.editMetadata(true)
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, resources.getString(R.string.casting_episode, seriesItem.get().getName(), episodeItem.get().getEpisodeNumber()))
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST, resources.getString(R.string.casting_to, selectedDevice.get().getFriendlyName()))
            .putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, seriesImage.get())
            .apply();
            ctrlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    ctrlClient.setTransportControlFlags(RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP);
    audioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(ctrlClient);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);
    remoteControlClient = Optional.of(ctrlClient);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After registering your `RemoteControlClient`, you need to add it to the `MediaRouter`:

```
mMediaRouter.addRemoteControlClient(mRemoteControlClient);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.html#addRemoteControlClient(java.lang.Object)